# Limits in a metric function / Banach fixed point theorem inequality

Tags: analysis

I am trying to prove that in a Banach space $X$ for a

$F: X \rightarrow X$

with $x_n=F(x_{n-1})$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

and $d(F(x),F(y))\leq \gamma d(x,y)$ with $\gamma \in (0,1)$ $\forall x,y \in X$

with $x_0 \in X$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n=x$

the inequality holds:
$d(x_{n+1}, x) ≤ γd(x_n, x)$

My attempt is:

$d(x_{n+1}, x_{n+1+i})=  d(F(x_{n}), F(x_{n+i}))\leq \gamma d(x_n, x_{n+i})$

I am pretty sure it would be formally false to just let $i \to \infty$ inside the metric function, but the inequality looks like the right way to prove it. How could I proceed?

Comment: Use that $F(x) = x$ (prove that).

Comment: $F$ ist Lipschitz-continuous, because its contractive, so it immediately follows. My problem was with the distance functions, which are not necessarily continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we check Banach fixed point theorem and remark that all requirements are set. Therefor:

(1) $\quad F(x) = x$

from what you said we know that:

(2) $\quad d(F(x),F(y))\leq \gamma d(x,y)$ with $\gamma \in (0,1)$ $\forall x,y \in X$

(3) $\quad x_n=F(x_{n-1})$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

We want to show that:

(4) $\quad d(x_{n+1}, x) ≤ γd(x_n, x)$

It follows from (1), (3):

(5) $\quad d(F(x_n), F(x)) ≤ γd(x_n, x)$

But (2) states that this is true.

QED

Answer (score 1):

Let $n\ge 0$ and $a\in X $  fixed.

$$(\forall p>0) \;\; d (x_{n+1},x_p)\le \gamma d (x_n,x_{p-1}) $$

The function $g:y \mapsto d (a,y)$ satisfies

$$|g (y)-g (z)|=|d(a,y)-d (a,z)|\le d(y,z)$$

and it is uniformly continuous at $X $.

thus, the first inequality above gives$$\lim_{p\to +\infty}d (x_{n+1},x_p)\le \gamma \lim_{p\to+\infty}d (x_n,x_{p-1}) $$

and
by continuity of $g $,
$$d (x_{n+1},x)\le \gamma d (x_n,x) $$